# How to list all entities in Azure table storage java

Tags: azure, storage

I am stuck at how to list all entities in table, now I am inserting the entity with a random partition key so its not fixed and cannot help me in lookup. Basically I want to do a select * from the azure table.

Below is the code I was trying

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
           CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

       // Create the table client.
       CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();
       
       CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("tablename");

      TableQuery<tablenameentity> query = new TableQuery<tablenameentity>();

      for(tablenameentity entity : cloudTable.execute(query) ){
           System.out.println(entity.getId() + " " + entity.getName());
           
       }
```

Fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The argument must not be null or an empty string. Argument name: Query requires a valid class type or resolver..

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-table-storage.md

Comment: Thanks I referred to this only, but this does not answer my question as it does not elaborate how to get all entities from table

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most ideal solution but since I had hardcoded the rowkey that will be inserted so I used the following code

String rowFilter = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(ROW_KEY, QueryComparisons.EQUAL, "17112022");

TableQuery query = TableQuery.from(TableEntity.class).where(rowFilter );